# esc_url removes white space. Can I change that to using '-'?

Tags: sanitization

I'm using [esc_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs) to sanitize my url. The only problem is that "my link" becomes "mylink". I wouldreally like it to become "my-link".

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = esc_url ( str_replace(' ' , '-', $url ) );
```

Replace the spaces to - chars before activating esc_url function, and your problem is solved.

Comment: I know - I was hoping that `esc_url` had a function so I didn't have to use `str_replace`. Thanks for your answer.